# updating mysql table on textarea blur?

Tags: php, sql, text, area

i am trying to make a text area update the information in a table in mysql when the user clicks out the text area. can someone guide me in the right direction please. This is what i have so far. im not getting any errors, but when i update it the changes arnt saving.

HTML CODE

```
    <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">

<textarea id="title" textarea name="title" rows="10" style="width: 456px; 
    margin-top:3px;
    text-align:left;
    margin-left:-2px;
    height: 120px;
    resize: none; 
    border: hidden;" data-id='$idbio'><?php echo $profile['bio'] ?> </textarea>
</form>
```

Javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('textarea').on('blur',function () {
    var titleVal = $(this).val(), id = $(this).data('id');        

    $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "changebio.php",
         data: {title:titleVal , id:id},
         success: function(msg) {
             $('#'+id).html(msg);
         }
   })
});

</script>
```

changebio.php

```
 <?php
require_once("session.php"); 
require_once("functions.php");
require('_config/connection.php');
update_profilebio ();
header('Location: http://www.something.com/confirm.php');
?>
```

function.php

```
 function update_profilebio() {
            global $connection;
            global $profile_id;
            $query = "UPDATE ptb_profiles
                      SET bio='value'
                        WHERE ptb_profiles.user_id = \"$profile_id\"
                        AND ptb_profiles.user_id = ptb_users.id";
            $update_profilebio_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
            confirm_query($update_profilebio_set);
            return $update_profilebio_set;

            }
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? What is the problem?

Comment: firstly should it not be: 
$('#title').on('blur',function () {

Comment: probably i'll try that. but can anoyone advise me if ive written the function correctly. i.e i want it to update the table collum 'bio' in ptb_profiels. i dont know whether thats the problem.

Comment: @Brian i think if he needs multiple textareas all using the same event, that selector should work. This wont tho: `$('#'+id).html(msg);` as the id is not the selector but value of the `data-id` value is.

Comment: So what are the errors anyway? what is `$idbio` in `data-id='$idbio'` for it to work it will need to be the value 'title'.

Comment: Also... the header() might be throwing the AJAX call... Simply get it to display some yes/no value rather than re-direct that is in changebio.php

Comment: Check wheter the `changebio.php` gets called at all (custom server-side log file, Apache log, Firebug extension). Then make sure the SQL query is correct. Remember to escape the actual content in your `UPDATE` query to secure against possible SQL injection.

Comment: i'm not getting errors. just when i type in the text area it won't change the text, thus its not updating in the database. so if anything its unresponsive.

Comment: Hint... using firebug can you see anything being fired off when you expect?

Answer (score 0):

There are allot of *possible* reasons why this wont work. Many of these can be quickly checked via console in a decent browser.

What I can see that *may* cause an issue is the success after the AJAX call (meaning the AJAX call would need to be successful). You try to assign the HTML returned value back as `$('#'+id).html(msg);` where `id` is not actually the selector in this case,: `id = $(this).data('id')` its the data id.

I personally would append the `$idbio` to the end of the id attribute, something like this:

```
  <textarea id="title-<?php echo $idbio;?>" textarea name="title" data-id="<?php echo $idbio;?>">
    <?php echo $profile['bio'] ?>
  </textarea>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    $('textarea').on('blur',function () {
        var titleVal = $(this).val(), 
            id = $(this).data('id');        

        $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "changebio.php",
             data: {title:titleVal , id:id},
             success: function(msg) {
                 $('#title-' + id).val(msg);
             }
       })
    });

  </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Why are you using "on" method?? You could just do this: "$('textarea').blur(function(){...});", and i don't know what does the "data" method that you used here: "$(this).data('id')", when i want to get a id in my node i just to this: "$(this).attr('id');", and another thing, you get the string from textarea in the first time with the method "val()", and after that, you try to put a string with "html()", there is something wrong with that.

Comment: .blur gets turned into 'on.('blur',...' internally so it's equivalent.

Comment: Makes zero difference. It actually gives flexibility if in future he wants to allow other events to trigger it.